# Using parallel to sg_format 300+ drives

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnu-parallel

Some time ago I learned about the software parallel: https://forums.servethehome.com/index.php?threads/mdadm-create-raid-0-quick-format.41161/#post-389210

Now I have almost the same goal as previous, but I want to try and do it differently.

For setup I have:

Dell SFF desktop with single port SAS2 HBA

Total of 14 NetApp SAS3 disk shelf

Each disk shelf has 24x 960GB 12G SAS SSD's mounted

The drives run 520 sector size

The goal is to run sg_format --format -e /dev/sgXX on all the drives, preferably using parallel.

It could be done one by one but I'd like to do it using parallel to learn how it functions and potentially get this done faster for all future projects like this.

I use Ubuntu 23.10, added universe repository, used apt update and apt install parallel. Parallel is now installed as well as sg3-utils and smartmontools.

My HBA can handle 128 devices, where device 1 (or 0) is the HBA itself, so I have a total of 5 disk shelves running in a chain, which means I have 120 drives attached. They start at /dev/sg2 and end at /dev/sg126.

The command I used is:
parallel sg_format --format -e ::: /dev/sg[2-126]

When running it, the terminal freeze up for a few seconds, which is to be expected I guess.

However it is only /dev/sg2 and /dev/sg6 that are actually running, see image below.
[image: Image of only sg2 and sg6 running format]

All the drives are exactly the same, but only 2 of them want to actually start the format. I get no errors or any reason why all of them are not starting.

I have tried to start the drives "manually" so just using the sg_format command, and all of them start with no issues here.

If I run the command

parallel sg_format --format -e ::: /dev/sg[2-10]

It runs sg_format on /dev/sg2 and then on /dev/sg0, only those two.

Surely I have a problem when entering multiple devices.

Does anyone know?

Comment: Are you sure that latter one with `/dev/sg[2-10]` runs it on `/dev/sg2`? What shell are you running? Try e.g. `echo "bash:$BASH_VERSION zsh:$ZSH_VERSION`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's because you are using `/dev/sg[2-126]`. Unfortunately, ranges don't handle multi-digit numbers. They are *character* ranges, and `126` is not a character. So while you can have `[0-9]`, you cannot have `[0-10]` since that would mean "the characters from 0 to 1, and then 0". So your `[2-126]` actually means "the number between 2 and 1" which is meaningless since 2 is after 1, and then the specific numbers `2` and `6`. This is why you are only matching `sg2` and `sg6`.

So your first command, `parallel sg_format --format -e ::: /dev/sg[2-126]`, is running on `sg2` and `sg6`. And your second command, `parallel sg_format --format -e ::: /dev/sg[2-10]` runs on `/dev/sg2` and `/dev/sg0` because `[2-1]` is interpreted as the single character `2` since there are no other characters between `2` and `1`, and then the `0` is taken as itself.

What you want is to use [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) instead:

```
parallel sg_format --format -e ::: /dev/sg{2..126}
```

Or, to run as many jobs as possible at once, use:

```
parallel -j0 sg_format --format -e ::: /dev/sg{2..126}
```

Comment: Also `-j0` if you do not have 125 CPU threads.

Comment: @OleTange oh, I thought `parallel` would default to something like running as many processes as there are CPUs when not given `-j`. Are you saying it will try to run _all_ commands at once if not told otherwise?

Comment: parallel by default runs 16 processes for me, with -j 0 it runs >200 and complains about various runtime limits :-)

Comment: Your interpretation is correct (except it is technically not CPUs - it is CPU threads), but I assumed OP wanted to run as many jobs in parallel as possible. I would assume `sg_format` is not very CPU heavy, so running >100 `sg_formats` in parallel would be fine even on a single core machine.

Comment: @frostschutz It should *warn*  about runtime limits, but still do The Right Thing. ("Complain" may be interpreted as failing - which it should not do).

Comment: but then you would not need parallel, you could just run `for drive in /dev/sg{1..128}; do thing "$drive" & done` for pretty much the same thing. it could be fine in this case, I don't know

Comment: `/dev/sg[2-126]` should match `/dev/sg2` and `/dev/sg6` only, since the range `2-1` doesn't contain anything (since `2` comes after `1`). That's what I get in Bash, Dash and zsh anyway, e.g. `touch foo{1..9} foo-; echo foo[2-126]` prints `foo2 foo6`. (Some other shells treat that as an invalid glob and don't expand it at all.) Which also means `/dev/sg[2-10]` should only match `/dev/sg0`, I can't see how it could match `/dev/sg2`.

Comment: (Fun fact, Junos (the software on Juniper network devices) allows e.g. `foo[0-11]` for matching `foo0`, `foo1`, `foo2`... `foo11`. It's somewhat jarring.)

Comment: @ilkkachu um. Yeah, that's what I get in bash too. Can you find where this is documented though? I quote `man glob` which states that `[ ]` matches a single character and suggests that `[x-z]` won't be a list from `x` to `z` but instead the three characters `x`, `-` and `z`. However, you're absolutely right and `[1-3]` will match `1`, `2` or `3` in bash just like a regular regex character class.

Comment: @terdon, the Debian man page for glob mentions ranges too, just after character classes: https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/manpages/glob.7.en.html And Bash's manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html The POSIX text refers to the regexp definitions on that part (I don't have the link right now)

Comment: @Jelle my explanation may have been detailed, but it was also completely wrong. Please see updated answer which now has the right explanation. Globs absolutely do support ranges,  I don't know what I was thinking. The problem is that they get ranges of characters, numbers are characters, which means that `10` is two characters, `1` and `0`, not the number `10`.

Comment: Thanks, @ilkkachu. Wow. Serious brainfart on my part there.

Comment: @terdon, I don't think you were that wrong, the main point that `[2-126]` isn't as useful as they'd hope was there to begin with. I still wonder about the claim in the Q about `[2-10]` matching `2`, it doesn't fit what I saw in practice.

Comment: Thank you all for adding more information. I understood how it works in detail now. I have already implemented this for the future when we get drives like this. In the future I want to set up the SAN the drives belong to, and use that to clear the drives, but these were SSD's and it took about 2 minutes to do the format on, which is fair enough. Sometimes we have 8TB drives, which can be a challenge if I don't want to have them running for days.